# Excel: search if a specific text exists in a column

Tags: excel

I have two columns. Each cell in column A contains a full sentences and each cell in column B contains a word or phrase. I would like to check if the contents of each cell in column B appears in one of the cells in column A---it could appear in multiple cells in column A or in no cells. The output just needs to be a yes or no (and should be spit out in column C) for my purposes, but it would be neat to return the number of times each column B word came up somewhere in Column A.

So far I haven't figured out how to take a discrete string of letters (already printed in one cell) and search across a range in a column. Not sure if this is beyond the regular excel functionality.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Can there be multiple times the words in B in the same cell A? (e.g. `word word` in cell A1 and you have `word` in cell B1 to look for. Do you need to return the result 2 since it appears twice?)

Answer (score 3):

Use array formula like this:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,A:A,1)),0,1))
```

enter in formula bar then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
Hope this helps.
Put formula in C.

Comment: + 1 Nice one :) However this might be ineffective if OP wants what @Jerry mentioned in the comment above :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout yeah :) but he started a simple question so i provided a simple answer. haha...

Comment: Thanks, for my purposes, I didn't need to do what Jerry asked about. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
=countif(a:a,"*" & b2 & "*")>0  gives you result in True/Flase
```

To get the occurrence

```
=countif(a:a,"*" & b2 & "*")
```

To get YES/NO

```
=if(countif(a:a,"*" & b2 & "*")>0,"YES","NO")
```