# Search for duplicate text string in two columns and highlight, excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to search and highlight duplicate text strings in two different columns in Excel; this means that the cell content doesn't have to be identical, instead of that is what I need is that if the content of column A is somehow contained in any cell of column B, both cells get highlighted.

For example, let's say that I have two columns, one named "Patient" and another one called "Couples". So, what I would need is to make a comparison between both columns, and if one of the patient's names is within a couple, both cells get highlighted:

```
Column A. Patient name  |  Column B. Couple name
John Smith              |  Adriana Lewis - Mark Rutte
Peter Brown             |  Giaccomo Down - Rosy Lawn
Jerry Goldsmith         |  Bob Loewe - Gigi Pink
Ewan Thompson           |  Sonia Farrel - John Smith
```

In this example, the content of A2 ("John Smith") is also contained in B5 ("Sonia Farrel - John Smith"), so that I would need that both A2 and B5 get highlighted. Also, both columns don`t have the same range, one is shorter than the other, since there are more names than couples; and it can happen that two names in different cell are contained in a single couple, so that all three cells should get highlighted.

I have tried everything, with no success... please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: search if a specific text exists in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395813/excel-search-if-a-specific-text-exists-in-a-column)

Comment: Since you have "tried everything" you should probably post the code that comes closest to what you want it to do and ask a specific question instead of asking for someone to write the code from scratch. Consider also reading the Stack Overflow [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and taking the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then you can edit your question and make it better.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ways to do this but here's one option with conditional formatting.

1. Rule applied to data in column A, using `COUNTIF` and wildcards.

   ```
   =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,"*"&A2&"*")>0
   ```
2. Rule applied to data in column B, using `ISNUMBER`, `SEARCH` and `SUMPRODUCT`.

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,B2)))>0
   ```

[image]